# Is this code synchronous as I want it to be?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I have this code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
{
  if (query == null)
  {
     throw new ArgumentNullException("query cannot be null");
  }

  DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery =
 _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

  return await Task.Factory.FromAsync
                 (webQuery.BeginExecute(null, null)
                 , asyncResult => webQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult)
                 );
}
```

I call it thus

```
public static void Main()
{
   Search().Wait();
}

private static async Task Search()
{
  IWebSearcher webSearcher = new WebSearcher();
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
      IEnumerable<WebResult> task = await webSearcher.SearchAsynch(i.ToString());

      var enumerator = task.GetEnumerator();
      enumerator.MoveNext();
      Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Title);
   }
}
```

The issue I have is this.  I want each of these 100 calls to `SearchAsynch` to be totally independant of each other so that the 10th call might return and print its result before the 9th call.  This does not seem to be happening at this moment.  Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do processing as tasks complete is to define a separate method that does the processing, as such:

```
public static async Task SearchAndPrintAsync(IWebSearcher webSearcher, string query)
{
  var result = await webSearcher.SearchAsync(query);
  using (var enumerator = result.GetEnumerator())
  {
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
      Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Title);
    else
      Console.WriteLine("<none>");
  }
}
```

Then you can do concurrent `async` operations as such:

```
private static async Task MainAsync()
{
    IWebSearcher webSearcher = new WebSearcher();

    // Start all SearchAndPrint operations concurrently.
    Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        .Select(i => SearchAndPrintAsync(webSearcher, i))
        .ToArray();

    // Wait for them all to complete.
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
```

Comment: The `SearchAndPrintAsync` method is violating separation of concerns.  It's mixing data access with presentation.

Comment: I'm assuming the op only gave us sample code, so `Console.WriteLine` logically represents "do further processing".

Comment: BTW, I think that using `First()` (or `FirstOrDefault()`) would be simpler here than fiddling with enumerators. (But I realize you just copied that from the question and fixed it.)